# have you ever seen during runtime that an object (C#) returns null after constructing it?

Tags: c#, constructor

I know it is a strange question did someone have had a case where a C# object return null after newing it up?

Comment: Are you experiencing this problem? If it was a C/C++ application I'd say you were running out of memory.

Comment: I've heard of such stories on ancient machines which had insufficient free memory for a program to run.

Comment: What's in your constructor? You might be throwing an exception and depending on your exception handling you might be missing it.

Comment: Constructors don't return anything - could you be a little more precise - code snippet might help.

Comment: Thanks for all people answered. No was not a trick question! But it ends up that the developer looked into the wrong sources and therefore this was misleading us. Sorry!!

Comment: I've done that a few times.  There's nothing more frustrating than your debugger telling you that True == False.

Comment: I am afraid that's life and I was a not systematic enough. Sorry!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not possible by design, you'll always get an OutOfMemory exception if a new object cannot be created.  A corrupted garbage collected heap is technically possible, invariably triggered by misbehaving unmanaged code, but I never heard of any cases where that didn't trigger an ExcecutionEngineException.

Answer (score 6):

Is this a trick question?

```
int? i = new int?();

if (i == null)
    Console.WriteLine("It's null!");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking he's got failing logic in the constructor of his object. There's no way this is happening to an object native to the asp.net framework.